# Authenticated API on separate domain?

Tags: ajax

How can I set up an ajax application to have an API that requires authentication on a separate domain? For example, I have an app called exampleapp located at exampleapp.com. I want to have ajax calls sent to api.exampleapp.com, but I want to make sure only authenticated users can use the API. Are there any articles, books, tutorials, etc. that would explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you planning to create those API's? Using any existing WS frameworks?

Comment: I was planning on creating them from scratch. I was unaware there were frameworks for this sort of thing. What is a WS framework?